# VSTO comment RCW points to the wrong comment

Tags: com, vsto, ms-office, office-interop, word-interop

I've come across a very strange behavior in Word VSTO. I don't know why it is happening or how to avoid it. I can demonstrate it with the following code. If `_comment` is set, then show its content in a MessageBox. If `_comment` is not set, then set it to the first comment in the document.

```
    private void Application_DocumentBeforeSave(Word.Document Doc, ref bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        if(_comment != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(_comment.Range.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            var comments = Application.ActiveDocument.Range().Comments;
            if (comments.Count > 0)
            {
                _comment = comments[1];
            }
        }
    }
```

The strange behavior happens when the user adds a second comment with the exact same scope as the first. When that happens, _comment refers to the second comment instead of the first.

**_comment is set to some comment:**
[image: _comment is set]

**The user adds a second comment with the same scope as the first (when nothing is highlighted, the word the cursor is in will be selected)**
[image: Second comment is inserted inside scope of first comment, without highlighting anything.]

**_comment now refers to the second comment, for some reason:**
[image: Second comment]

[image: _comment now points to the second comment for some reason.]

Can anyone explain what is happening here? Am I missing something, or is this a bug in the interop?

Comment: It's just how Word works. You get a reference to "the first comment" (the one with Index property set to 1), but what is or what represents "the first comment" evolves over time.

Comment: @SimonMourier I don't think that's it. If you insert a comment earlier in the document then that is the first item in the document's comments collection, but the reference is unchanged - it still refers to the comment it was set to, even though its index is now 2.